# Laravel validation with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've included this Github [script](https://github.com/RyanSMurphy/Laravel-Bootstrap-Modal-Form/blob/master/README.md) to make a validation form with Bootstrap Modal everything is set up correctly but when I included this script the form don't submit because there are some errors which is good but it doesn't show them in the view

Controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'nom' => 'required|unique:filieres'
]);
```

View

```
@if($errors->get('nom'))
    @foreach($errors->get('nom') as $error)
        <li class="has-error">{{$error}}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

can you just type this code in your view file

```
        @include('includes.form_error')
```

second type this in your controller

```
    public function store(UsersRequest $request)
    {
    }
```

and you create UserRequest file in Requests folder and type this

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

after you got proper error

Comment: View [includes.form_error] not found.
from where you got this view?

Comment: please see the link below for more information https://github.com/LMS-Laravel/LMS-Laravel/issues/9